# Which level of management or UX hierarchy has the responsibility for setting the design code of ethics for the organisation?

Tags: standards, ethics, governance

I believe that in a graphics or visual design setting, the creative director or artistic director would be responsible for this. However, in many organisations the hierarchy or level of governance for UX design work is not always very clear, so I am wondering if anyone can name the position that is responsible for maintaining the professional and ethical standards of UX design in their organisation, or if it is in the 'too hard basket' and generally passed onto the product owner or senior manager (or HR).

Comment: The person who invented clippy would surely have violated the Code.

Comment: @Mayo in what way?

Comment: @RobertHarvey - He is apparently a teacher in Bellevue Washington now. A co-worker of mine tells me that his son's teacher has claimed to be this person. I really want to meet this man.

Answer (score 1):

"Be the change you want to see in the world, yo"

I say, if you have a set of ideas about this kind of thing yourself, and you're not seeing them being answered or espoused anywhere else, I'd start compiling and presenting your ideas to your 'best bet candidates' within the organisation; don't wait for someone else to start having the conversations you'd like them to be having about the work you do.

Comment: A very good point, but as I work as a contractor it is not usually something that the clients particularly like to spent money (and therefore my time) on. I ask the question also because normally there is no one in particular that I can address these concerns to within the organisation, or externally if I feel that the work breaches certain design or ethical considerations. Having made the point in your answer, who would be your 'best bet candidates' within your organisation?

Comment: Specifically, I'd say then that your best point of contact is your most immediate. Naturally, if this is something that's important to you as you work, make it an integrated part of how you communicate and frame your work. Put the conversation (and questions you have) in context, and hopefully that will pave the way for any 'bigger picture' conversations you want to have.

Comment: Maybe good advice, but this doesn't answer the question.

Comment: I didn't feel I could give it a specific answer largely because all organisations are different. What's true for one might not be for another.

Comment: "All organisations are different" would be a perfectly valid answer to the question.

Comment: I guess I was trying to offer something more 'instructive' than that, and hope that fact was otherwise implied.

Answer (score 1):

This question is somewhat parallel to a question like, 
Who's responsibility is it for setting and maintaining the safety standards in a company?

The answer for this is most likely that there's no set position for this. That it just happens (or doesn't) within the company's culture. and sometimes (maybe once a year) there's an safety audit by a 3rd party to check if the company follows standards.

Reality is, while there are standards in safety and in UX, not everyone follows them. nor can a governing body or a specialist regulate these. There are benefits of bringing a 3rd party into to routine audits. however unless the company culture gives some focus on good ux practices, things will snap back to the way they were once the audit is over.

Few ways I've learned to do this. which might help are

- Inspiring and leading by example
- Educating colleagues and making it a fun thing
- Setting up resources like styleguide or pattern libraries that would make like easier for people working with the product
- recognizing and rewarding good ux practices

Comment: Well, at least in Australia there is a position called Workplace Health and Safety Officer that takes care of all safety related issues. I am still curious as to why no one can provide any examples of a person who has taken on the responsibility for this within an organisation...

Comment: it might be because ux is still relatively new, and the consequences of bad ux resulting in something harmful hasn't been realized yet. 

Imagine an auto accident resulting by not following these guides
https://www.google.com/design/spec-auto/designing-for-android-auto/designing-for-cars.html then a position to enforce proper ux will become very urgent

Comment: I think we've already seen what can happen with the VW emission testing scandal that has done much to damage the reputation of the company and those involved in the automobile industry already. Luckily it is not to do with a safety issue, but it definitely has provided the public with some idea of what can happen without strong ethical standards in design practice.